# Connect via SMB to Amazon EC2 local storage

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, cifs

This is similar to [Unable to Share Data between Amazon EC2 Instances for Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/228468/unable-to-share-data-between-amazon-ec2-instances-for-windows#)

However in my case I am trying to connect from an external machine to a shared folder on an EC2 Windows 2012 machine.

I've enabled sharing as far as I can tell and opened TCP port 445 in a security group, but I can't seem to connect. Even running a plain

`telnet my-ec2-ip 445`

from an IP that should be within the security group times out without a connection.

I know this isn't necessarily the most recommended way to get files from my EC2 instance, but I need to do this from a tool that has very limited connectivity options and this may be my best bet. What might I be missing that would let this connection work?

Comment: Checked windows firewall ??

Comment: As best I could, yes, but tbh I am not a Windows expert so I was flying a bit blind in that respect.

Comment: Just for the record, in threads and email archives on other sites, it was generally suggested to use Dropbox, or ExpanDrive with S3, or something of that sort. I ended up going in that direction.